# Help to write a formula

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to write this equation from the image.[image]

This is what I tried but I am getting an error about math mode only

```
\begin{equation}
 v_\pi(s) = \mathbb{E}(G\textsubscript{t}\mid S\textsubscript{t} = s) = 
  \mathbb{E}\textsubscript{\pi} (\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \gamma^k R\textsubscript{t+k+1} \mid S\textsubscript{t} = s)
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: Why `\textsubscript`? It should be `R_{t+k+1}` and similarly in the other cases.

Comment: You can play with Mathpix FREELY.

Comment: Find Mathpix here: https://mathpix.com/

Answer (score 4):

As any beginner's guide to LaTeX will tell you, math subscripts are entered prefixing them with `_`. As the name says, `\textsubscript` is for subscripts in *text mode* (the command itself was added rather recently).

Exactly like in `v_{\pi}`: why should the other cases be different?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
v_{\pi}(s)
= \mathbb{E}_{\pi}[G_{t}\mid S_{t} = s]
= \mathbb{E}_{\pi} \biggl[\,\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \gamma^k R_{t+k+1} \biggm| S_{t} = s\biggr]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]